# How to print different path colors depending on values?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts, scatter-plot

I have this simple scatter plot, with a path:

[image: Scatter plot]

What I need to do is color the line with these colors:

- Green when it increase
- Red when it decrease

To resume what I´m doing, this is the part where I create the path and color the line.

```
svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(newData)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.EarningsX); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.EarningsY); })
    .attr("r", 8)
    .style("fill", "#69b3a2")

path = svg.append("path")
    .datum(newData)
    .attr("d", d3.line().x(function(d) {
        return x(d.EarningsX)
    }).y(function(d) {
        return y(d.EarningsY)
    }))
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "#69b3a2")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: under the SVG 1 specifications, you can't.

There are ways to paint a `<path>` element with different colours, but they involve complicated steps, like using gradients, but even that won't work in your specific case.

The good news is that you're using **straight lines**, and not curves. Because of that, you can simply drop the `<path>` and use several `<line>` elements, which you can paint individually.

Here is a demo of a simple line chart using a `<path>`:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg")
const data = d3.range(30).map(d=>[d*10, Math.random()*150]);
const path = svg.append("path")
 .datum(data)
  .attr("d", d3.line());
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

As you can see, the path has one colour, and one colour only.

Now let's change that code for appending several `<line>` elements. The interesting part here is using [`d3.pairs`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#pairs) for creating a pair of arrays based on the data. In the following demo, it's simply this:

```
const dataForTheLines = d3.pairs(data);
```

I don't know your data structure, but using `d3,pairs` is quite simple.

Then, we paint the lines according to the condition. In the case of the demo below, it is:

```
.style("stroke", d => d[1][1] < d[0][1] ? "red" : "green")
```

And here is the demo:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg")
const data = d3.range(30).map(d => [d * 10, Math.random() * 150]);
const dataLines = d3.pairs(data);
const lines = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(dataLines)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1", d => d[0][0])
  .attr("x2", d => d[1][0])
  .attr("y1", d => d[0][1])
  .attr("y2", d => d[1][1])
  .style("stroke-width", "2px")
  .style("stroke", d => d[1][1] > d[0][1] ? "red" : "green")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```